# How to include a php script in all HTTP requests coming to the server

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a file called `init.php` which I want to get automatically included in each and every HTTP request coming to my server. My server is on LAMP configuration with PHP 5.3 and fast CGI. Any method to achieve this is welcome.

What I have already tried:

**I have already tried the `auto_prepend_file` method with `.htaccess` file but no success.**

I have done the following.

`.htaccess` File:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file /home/user/domain.com/init.php
```

`init.php` file:

```
<?php
echo "statement 2";
?>
```

`index.php` file:

```
statement 1
```

So, now if I visit http://domain.com/ I find only statement 1 getting printed. statement 2 is not getting printed.

Kindly let me know how to correct this or if there is any other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My server is on LAMP configuration with PHP 5.3 and fast CGI.

You can not set PHP ini directives with the `.htaccess` method with FCGI/CGI. You need to apply the changes within the php.ini or better the [user ini files <sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) instead.

Place a file called `.user.ini` into the document root and add the [`auto_prepend_file`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/auto_prepend_file) directive in there:

```
auto_prepend_file = /home/user/domain.com/init.php
```

This should do the job for you.

Comment: That's for what is has been made for :)

Comment: Is the prepend file also executed when the user tries to access a non-php file, such as an image?

Comment: @Rapti: It is always *prepended* when PHP code is executed. Prepending PHP code in front of a binary image file does not make much sense unless the PHP runtime then "executes" such image (that is push it out via STDOUT, so even what you ask about is not much likely, it is possible. Short answer probably is *no* what you ask for, but can be *yes* but that *yes* must not mean what you think it could mean)

Answer (score 5):

> My server is on LAMP configuration with PHP 5.3 and fast CGI.

fast CGI means no .htaccess directive would work. Change your php.ini instead.

> automatically included in each and every HTTP request

with auto_prepend_file you obviously can't include a php file to "each and every HTTP request", but to requests routed to PHP files only.