# How to include a php script in all HTTP requests coming to the server - without htaccess (PHP 5.2)

Tags: php

I'm using a framework that sets various php directives inside an .htaccess file. However, my hosting provider does not have mod_php enabled, meaning I can't do this in the usual way via a .htaccess file. To complicate matters further, I'm using PHP 5.2, so I can't use the .user.ini files suggested in this question.

[How to include a php script in all HTTP requests coming to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625425/how-to-include-a-php-script-in-all-http-requests-coming-to-the-server)

Can someone please tell me if there's a way to include a php file in all of my http requests (for other php files, not css or js of course :) so I can set some basic directives like include path, error logging, etc for any php page that the user visits?

Thanks

Comment: Is `require` or `include` not a valid solution for some reason?

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to do this without having to manually include/require a php config file for every view I create. It would be nice to have the same/similar convenience that a .htaccess file offers - but unfortunately that specific option is unavailable to me. I'm looking for something comparable to that method though (something more automatic)

Comment: to be 100% sure that the script is run on all pages, you would *NEED* either php.ini or htaccess. Other than that, there is most likely a top level page that gets included/loaded everywhere the framework is loaded. You could just include at that level and it would be available everywhere that uses the framework.

Comment: @jerry If you have a well structured application, you should already have a common set of base includes that get run for every page load.  Also, might want to reconsider hosts if they don;t give you something so basic as the ability to use `.htaccess`

Comment: @Mike Brant, can you provide a link to an example of this method for having a set of base includes for every page load? I might need to restructure this app

Comment: @Jerry  No need for a link.  Just the first line in any file might be something like `require('app_init.php');` or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is just use a single URL, and use a parameter to specify which controller should be called i.e.

index.php?cmd=address

index.php?cmd=user

inside index.php:

```
<?php 

$myFrontController = new FrontController();

$myFrontController->processRequest($_REQUEST);
```

then inside your front controller:

```
function processRequest($requestArray) {
    $command = $requestArray['cmd'];
    $commandClass = 'Command_' . $command ;
    if(file_exists('commands/'.$commandClass.'.php')) {
        include_once('commands/' . $commandClass . '.php');
        $commandInstance =  new $commandClass;
    }
    $commandInstance->processRequest($requestArray);

}
```

Comment: But how would I tell the server to route all requests to the index.php which invokes the front controller above? For instance, if I have a link on my site to about.php, then how can I tell the web server to automatically route it to the index page (to process the request) without .htaccess?

Comment: don't link to about.php. link to index.php?cmd=about .. when you finally do an htaccess or rewrite rule on a different host, you can then do a find/replace on index.php?cmd=(cmd) and change it to point to app/(cmd) or even just /(cmd) . otherwise, your only option is to use php.ini or .htaccess